# Problem with passing values from checkboxes and displaying them in another page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am building an application for ads/properties in Laravel. I have profile page with users info that can be updated. In there I have user preference section where I can check one or more checkboxes (house, flat) and based on what I checked after submission of form I want to show properties/ads that have those values on start page. Currently when I submit form I get success message, but no results are displayed on startpage. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here are my tables and code.

```
users (id, first_name)

properties (id, user_id, title, location, price, etc...)

properties_categories (id, property_id, category_id)

categories (id, category)
```

In category column in categories table are values house, flat, apartment, room.

UserController.php

```
public function update(StoreUserInfo $request, User $user)
{
    if ( !($user->id == Auth::user()->id)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $request->validated();

    $user->where('id', $user->id)->update(
        [
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
        ]
    );

    $query = Property::query();

    if ($request->has('propertyType1')) {
        $request->get('propertyType1');
    }

    $propertyType1 = $request->input('propertyType1');

    if (!empty($propertyType1)) {
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($propertyType1) {
            $query->whereIn('category', $propertyType1);
        });
    }

    $resultsFiltered = $query->where('active', 'Q')
    ->orWhere('active', 'A')
    ->orderBy('page_views', 'desc')
    ->with('user.photo', 'photos', 'category')->paginate(5);

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'User information updated')->with(compact('resultsFiltered'));
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('user.update',['id'=>$user->id]) }}">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name',$user->first_name) }}" required autocomplete="first_name" autofocus>
            @error('first_name')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row page-hero d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <label for="preferences" class="text-center">Select your preferences</label>         
    </div>
    <div class="row">                
        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:15px; margin-left:60px;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input id="house" name="propertyType1[]" value="house" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="house">house</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:15px;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input id="flat" name="propertyType1[]" value="flat" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="flat">flat</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:50px;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input id="apartment" name="propertyType1[]" value="apartment" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="apartment">apartment</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:15px;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input id="room" name="propertyType1[]" value="room" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="room">room</label>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
        <button form="form" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Save changes
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

startpage.blade.php

```
<div class="col-2">
    <h1>Prefered ads</h1>
        @if (isset($resultsFiltered))
            @foreach ($resultsFiltered as $resultFiltered)
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="{{route('property.show',['id'=>$resultFiltered->id])}}">
                        @if ($resultFiltered->active == 'A')
                            <button class="btn btn-success" disabled="dissabled">Verified</button>
                        @endif
                        <img  class="img-fluid" src="/storage/{{$resultFiltered->main_photo['original_src']}}/{{$resultFiltered->main_photo['filename']}}" alt="Card image cap">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled style="margin-top:10px;">{{$resultFiltered->price}} eur</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled style="margin-top:10px;">{{$resultFiltered->quadrature}} m<sup>2</sup></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">{{$resultFiltered->city}}</button>
                        <hr>
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col">{{ $resultsFiltered->links() }}</div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        @endif
</div>
```

web.php

```
Route::put('/user/{user}', 'UserController@update')->name('user.update');
```

Property.php

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'properties_categories')->orderBy('priority', 'asc');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Category.php

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

User.php

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}

public function property()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Property', 'user_id', 'id')->where('active', 'Q')->orWhere('active', 'A');
}
```

Comment: are the preferences categories?

Comment: @party-ring yes they are.

Comment: can you please verify that your relationships work? can you get a random category (i.e. `$category = Category::first()`) and dump out the properties that are under that category `dd($category->properties());` and post that for me please?

Comment: I get this if I did everything right. BelongsToMany {#345 ▼
  #table: "category_property"
  #foreignPivotKey: "category_id"
  #relatedPivotKey: "property_id"
  #parentKey: "id"
  #relatedKey: "id"
  #relationName: "property"
  #pivotColumns: []
  #pivotWheres: []
  #pivotWhereIns: []
  #pivotValues: []
  +withTimestamps: false
  #pivotCreatedAt: null
  #pivotUpdatedAt: null
  #using: null
  #accessor: "pivot"
  #query: Builder {#157 ▶}
  #parent: Category {#346 ▶}
  #related: Property {#339 ▶}
  -currentlyAttached: null
}

Comment: should have told you to add `->get()` to the end, sorry

Comment: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'real-estate-laravel.category_property' doesn't exist (SQL: select `properties`.*, `category_property`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `category_property`.`property_id` as `pivot_property_id` from `properties` inner join `category_property` on `properties`.`id` = `category_property`.`property_id` where `category_property`.`category_id` = 1)

Comment: Okay so you definitely need to fix your relationships with your pivot tables :)

Comment: @party-ring How should I fix this? To make new table named category_property?

Comment: personally, in my properties table I would add a column called category_id which would link to the categories table. This way you could have a belongsTo relationship (a property belongs to a category) and a one to many relationship (a category belongs to many properties).

Answer (score 1):

I would think your problem is here, as the `$query` is on the property model and not the category model, so you would need to define both table and column in the whereIn.

```
if (!empty($propertyType1)) {
    $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($propertyType1) {
        $query->whereIn('category', $propertyType1);
    });
}
```

You would need to do this

```
if (!empty($propertyType1)) {
    $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($propertyType1) {
        $query->whereIn('properties_categories.category', $propertyType1);
    });
}
```

EDIT: Although there is a relationship set in your models you will still need to provide the table in your statement as your query is in the property model and not the category.

```
$query = Property::query();
```

As it stands you are looking for `property.category`, which doesn't exist.  What you need is `properties_categories.category`

Comment: I have relationship between categories and properties. I am triyng to get for example  all rooms when I click submit and then it would list all ads/properties that are rooms. And rooms is value in category column in categories table